# how to build Hierarchical array using specific key of single dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array which has employee details with his supervisor ID & I have to build Organization chart which will represent reporting hierarchy for that I need an array in a multidimensional array, I tried many ways but unable to build as per requirement. Anyone plz help me with the answer.

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [userID] => 336
        [fullName] => S G
        [employeeSupervisiorID] => 316
        [employeePhoto] => 1537274919.jpg
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [userID] => 316
        [fullName] => S J
        [employeeSupervisiorID] => 1
        [employeePhoto] => 1537274885.jpg
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [userID] => 337
        [fullName] => R K
        [employeeSupervisiorID] => 316
        [employeePhoto] => 1537274940.jpg
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [userID] => 405
        [fullName] => De B
        [employeeSupervisiorID] => 1
        [employeePhoto] => 1537274961.jpg
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [userID] => 418
        [fullName] => J D
        [employeeSupervisiorID] => 337
        [employeePhoto] => 1537274978.jpg
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [userID] => 420
        [fullName] => A S
        [employeeSupervisiorID] => 316
        [employeePhoto] => 1537274997.jpg
    )

[6] => stdClass Object
    (
        [userID] => 421
        [fullName] => Sanjay j
        [employeeSupervisiorID] => 1
        [employeePhoto] => 1537275044.png
    )

[7] => stdClass Object
    (
        [userID] => 423
        [fullName] => Test User
        [employeeSupervisiorID] => 336
        [employeePhoto] => 1537275091.jpg
    )

)
```

Now I have to convert that array in hierarchy mode like below

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [userID] => 316
                [fullName] => S J
                [employeeSupervisiorID] => 1
                [employeePhoto] => 1537274885.jpg
                [childern] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [userID] => 336
                                [fullName] => S G
                                [employeeSupervisiorID] => 316
                                [employeePhoto] => 1537274919.jpg
                                [childern] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array 
                                            (
                                                [userID] => 423
                                                [fullName] => Test User
                                                [employeeSupervisiorID] => 336
                                                [employeePhoto] => 1537275091.jpg
                                            )
                                    )
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [userID] => 337
                                [fullName] => R K
                                [employeeSupervisiorID] => 316
                                [employeePhoto] => 1537274940.jpg
                                [childern] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [userID] => 418
                                                [fullName] => J D
                                                [employeeSupervisiorID] => 337
                                                [employeePhoto] => 1537274978.jpg
                                            )
                                    )
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [userID] => 420
                                [fullName] => A S
                                [employeeSupervisiorID] => 316
                                [employeePhoto] => 1537274997.jpg
                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [userID] => 405
                [fullName] => De B
                [employeeSupervisiorID] => 1
                [employeePhoto] => 1537274961.jpg
                [childern] => 
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [userID] => 421
                [fullName] => Sanjay j
                [employeeSupervisiorID] => 1
                [employeePhoto] => 1537275044.png
                [childern] => 
            )

    )

 )
```

I have written two for each loop but it's giving me result till second order. Thanks in advance for your answer. Here is my code which I have tried.

```
    $arrEmpSupervisiorIDs = [];
    foreach ( $arrEmployeeDetails as $arrEmployeeDetail ) {
        $arrEmpSupervisiorIDs[$arrEmployeeDetail->employeeSupervisiorID][] = $arrEmployeeDetail;
    }

    $arrOrganizationChart = [];
    // Building Tree By admin user ID
    foreach ( $arrEmpSupervisiorIDs[$intAdminUserID] as $key => $objEmpSupervisiorID ) {
        $arrOrganizationChart[$intAdminUserID][$key] = (array) $objEmpSupervisiorID;
        $arrOrganizationChart[$intAdminUserID][$key]['childern'] = $arrEmpSupervisiorIDs[$objEmpSupervisiorID['userID']];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer below example to build the organization chart.

```
function buildChart($empArr, $parentId = 0) {
 $result = array();

 foreach ($empArr as $emp) {
    if ($emp['employeeSupervisiorID'] == $parentId) {
        $children = buildChart($empArr, $emp['userID']);
        if ($children) {
            $emp['children'] = $children;
        }
        $result[] = $emp;
    }
  }

  return $result;
}

$tree = buildChart($empArr);
```

Comment: Thanks, Sachin this is actually I want.